# Como fazer o download de um arquivo e abri-lo ao finalizar o download?

Tags: php, android, stream-de-arquivos, download, http-headers

Possuo uma aplicação Android, estou tentando realizar um download de um **.apk** e posteriormente abri-lo ao finalizar o download, segue o código utilizado:

```java
        /**
         * baixando arquivo na background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            String caminhoAtt = "/sdcard/download/bee/bee.apk";
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]); //f_url[0] é o endereço do arquivo(testado ta certinho)
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // Pegando tamanho do arquivo
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength(); //aqui retorna -1 não sei porque

                // input stream para ler arquivo - com 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // deletar o arquivo ja existente
                File file = new File(caminhoAtt);
                file.delete();                

                // Output stream para jogar o arquivo no sdcard
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(caminhoAtt); //aqui ocorre o erro

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // mostrando o progresso....
                    // depois disso o onProgressUpdate vai ser chamado
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // escrevendo os dados para o arquivo
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // dando flush no output
                output.flush();

                // fechando as streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                  util xutil = new util();
                  String cMsg = "*** MENSAGEM DE ERRO *** "+ e.getMessage();
                  xutil.showmessage(MainActivity.this,"O Download falhou.",cMsg.toString() );
                  xutil.SaveErrMensagem( cMsg );
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**Essa é outra parte do código que ainda não testei pois não passa da parte de cima:**

```java
        /**
         * Atualizando barra de progresso
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // colocando a porcentagem do progresso
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
       }

        /**
         * Depois de completar a tarefa de fundo
         * fecha o processDialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String url) {
//             fecha o dialog depois que o arquivo foi baixado
            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type); //está deprecated porem não sei outro comando
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/download/bee/bee.apk"; //caminho desejado para o arquivo baixado.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent); //abrindo o arquivo .apk baixado
        }
    }
```

Ao executar o comando:

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(caminhoAtt); //aqui ocorre o erro
```

Acontece o seguinte erro:

> /sdcard/download/bee/bee.apk: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Porém acredito que o problema é no download do arquivo pois o length dele retorna -1 como você vê no código comentado lá emcima.

**Gostaria de saber como fazer para o servidor não retornar -1 como content-length nos headers**

## O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: O `getContentLength()` retorna o valor do _header_ `content-length` presente na resposta da sua requisição HTTP. Esse _header_ pode não estar sendo incluído pelo servidor na resposta, o que faz o método retornar esse `-1` indicando "valor desconhecido".

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente vamos ao erro do `-1` sendo retornado por `getContentLength()`.

O getContentLength() retorna o valor do *header* `content-length` presente na resposta da sua requisição HTTP. Esse *header* pode não estar sendo incluído pelo servidor na resposta, o que faz o método retornar esse `-1` indicando "valor desconhecido".

Vou agora citar duas possíveis causas do erro `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`, veja aí:

1. Falta da permissão apropriada no `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
2. Caminho do arquivo incorreto: Por exemplo, ao invés de `/sdcard/download/bee/bee.apk` não seria `/mnt/sdcard/download/bee/bee.apk` ? Em todo caso, o mais correto é não usar valores *hard-coded* e sim dessa forma:

   String caminhoAtt = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/bee/bee.apk";

**Obs.:** Para ser mais "cri-cri/caxias/chato" ainda, use `File.separator` no lugar de "/", mas sinceramente o dia que o Android deixar de ser *Linux-based* ou então o *encoding* padrão trocar a codificação do caracter /, pode largar a programação que o mundo vai estar acabando... :)

Comment: Ok, isso me ajudou um pouco pra entender melhor isto tudo, porém não resolveu meu problema infelizmente. To tentando aqui de tudo se eu achar solução te aviso

Comment: Bah consegui utilizando uma outra solução parecida, e vi que um dos problemas era que a pasta "bee" não existia e o android não cria, rs. Mas preciso de uma coisa pra finalizar, como eu faço para o servidor me retornar o content-length??

Comment: @PauloRoberto Aí não é minha praia (você pode acrescentar a _tag_ `php` à pergunta, se for a linguagem _server-side_ que você está usando), mas acho que você vai precisar criar um script para servir arquivos.